# discord.js bot youtube link

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am creating a discord bot in discord.js (v12 version) and I wanted to include a command for music in it, but when I enter a link to a YouTube video in <> it throws an error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No video id found: undefined

I would like to add that when I write a link without <> everything works fine.

My code:

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}play`)) {
    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
    if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send("Musisz być na kanale głosowym!");
    const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
    if (!permissions.has(`CONNECT`)) return message.channel.send("Nie mam potrzebnych permisji by wejść na kanał głosowy!");
    if (!permissions.has(`SPEAK`)) return message.channel.send("Nie mam potrzebnych permisji by wejść na kanał głosowy!");

    const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[1]);
    const song = {
        title: songInfo.videoDetails.title,
        url: songInfo.videoDetails.video_url,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error

> "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No video id found:
> undefined"

is simply because ytdl cannot find a song with the link provided

This has a simple fix though.

Ytdl comes with the function `ytdl.validateURL("song link")`, which will make sure a valid link is provided, it will return `true` if yes and `false` if it is an invalid song link.

We could add these three lined to the code:

```js
// If the validateURL returns as false, which means it is not a valid link
if (!ytdl.validateURL(args[1])) {
    // Return asking the user to send a valid link
    return message.channel.send("Please send a valid song link");
}
```

The final code would look something like:

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}play`)) {
    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
    if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send("Musisz być na kanale głosowym!");
    const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
    if (!permissions.has(`CONNECT`)) return message.channel.send("Nie mam potrzebnych permisji by wejść na kanał głosowy!");
    if (!permissions.has(`SPEAK`)) return message.channel.send("Nie mam potrzebnych permisji by wejść na kanał głosowy!");

    if (!ytdl.validateURL(args[1])) {
        return message.channel.send("Please send a valid song link");
    }

    const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[1]);
    const song = {
        title: songInfo.videoDetails.title,
        url: songInfo.videoDetails.video_url,
    };
}
```